# Issue with Location dialog on Android Q Beta

Tags: android, android-activity, android-location

`Activity.RESULT_CANCELED (value == 0 )`always getting called in `onActivityResult()` even when OK is pressed on Location Dialog

I am showing location dialog to the user if the location is turned off in the device setting.

Following code is used -

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
builder.addLocationRequest(new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY));
builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(WifiList_Activity.this);

mSettingsClient
        .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                //Success Perform Task Here
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                switch (statusCode) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        try {
                            ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                            rae. startResolutionForResult(WifiList_Activity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                            Logger.log("GPS Unable to execute request.");
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        Logger.log("GPS Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Fix in Settings.");
                }
            }
        });
```

And the code in `onActivityResult()` is as below ,

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
        switch (resultCode) {

            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Logger.log("Result code in onACtivityresult CANCELED::"+resultCode);
                Logger.log("GPS User denied to access location");
                finish();
                break;


            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                //Success Perform Task Here
                Logger.log("Result code in onACtivityresult OK::"+resultCode);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is even if the user presses OK on the Location dialog, `Acivity.RESULT_CANCELED` is always getting called as the received resultCode is 0.

I have targeted the App for `Android Q`,

```
compileSDKVersion "android-Q'
targetSDKVersion 'Q'
```

Also, running the App on Android Q beta on a Pixel device.

> Expected - on OK press of location dialog, resultCode -1 should be
> returned in onActivityResult.
>
> Actual - Even if ok is pressed, the resultCode 0 is returned in
> onActivityResult.

Comment: You may try with this way - 

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/29ce0c8e4fafd62c82680f86a68021c773a1b356/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/MainActivity.java

Comment: Thanks for replying. I saw the code, it seems useful for getting the location updates. but my problem is different. It is related to the enabling the location on device settings. So, if the location is found turned off, I want to show user the dialog ( generated by - startResolutionForResult() method) , which is working as expected. The dialog appears. Dialog appears with "No thanks" and "Ok" option. Here is the problem... i.e, wether the user presses "no thanks" or "ok".... the resultCode received in onActivityResult() is always turns out to be 0, that is the problem.

Comment: FYI, someone made an ticket on AOSP https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140447198

Comment: I also facing the same issue on Android Q.